# Selectively restore specific databases from a complete mysqldump

Tags: mysql, backup-restoration

I have multiple Wordpress databases stored on a VPS. I am using the following command to back them up:

```
# mysqldump -u root -p password --all-databases > /tmp/all-database.sql
```

This creates a single file. Is there anyway to restore specific databases from this dump?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--one-database` option

> Ignore statements except those that occur while the default database is the one named on the command line. **This option is rudimentary and should be used with care. Statement filtering is based only on USE statements.**

so

```
mysql -u someone -p somedatabase <all.sql
```

*Should* work as you want and be reasonably safe for but note the emphasis above and read the [notes in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database)

It would probably be safer though to extract the database you want rm the dump.
Something like

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: somedatabase/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' all.sql > somedatabase.sql
```

where *somedatabase* is the name of the database you want to extract.